# Error running React Native App on Android emulator

Tags: android, react-native

When I start a HelloWorld App on react-native using "expo start" command getting the error below. The emulator is up and running . Expo go is already installed. But for some reason app is not installing. Any pointers to resolve this would be very helpful.

```
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: Error running app. args: [-p, host.exp.exponent, -c, android.intent.category.LAUNCHER, 1]
     arg: "-p"
     arg: "host.exp.exponent"
     arg: "-c"
     arg: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
     arg: "1"
    data="host.exp.exponent"
    data="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
    ** SYS_KEYS has no physical keys but with factor 2.0%.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Was able to resolve it by manually adding the url for the project on the expo go app in emulator and press Connect.

exp://192.168.0.22:19000

[image]

Comment: did you manage to solve it only with the manual url? when i try to enter the url manually expo go crashes in the emulator

Answer (score 0):

You may want to follow the instructions in the expo docs for setting up the android studio emulator: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/android-studio-emulator/ The docs very clearly guide you on the steps needed to setup everything such that you can just run `expo start -a` to start your app on the emulator